# Focus another process textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, process, textbox, focus, system

I'm just a begginer so don't blame me :D

I wanna know how the code for that (title) problem looks like :P

I mean  you got a button... (button1)
when you click , he/it will bring a process from taskmanager on desktop and will select a random textbox...

As example 
I press button1 and then chrome.exe starts and focuses the search bar

Comment: First thing i need to know is  how to bring a process on desktop if he stays  in taskbar/ focus a process .
Thanks !

Comment: This is a very frequent choice as a starter project for a programmer just starting out.  Unfortunately it is a very bad way to get started, messing with another program you didn't write is quite difficult.  Intentionally.  Put it on the shelf, pick another project.  Write your *own* program, mess with it as you please.